Optimization of Large "Primes in Range" solver?
I'm generating a large range of primes starting from a non-zero value.
e.g., Primes from 2^64 to 2^64+1,000,000. Due to not needing all primes from 0 - instead starting at 2^64 - a sieve is both slower and requires significantly more RAM.
I have it multithreaded, but I've attached the single-thread implementation for easier optimization.
Can this be parallelized via matrices to check primality faster? What are some methods for accelerating?
Using 2^32 to 2^32+1,000,000 below for example.
import gmpy2
import timeit

def primes_01(start, end):
    last_six_divisor_1 = start - (start % 6) + 1
    last_six_divisor_2 = start - (start % 6) + 5
    while last_six_divisor_1 < start:
        last_six_divisor_1 += 6
    while last_six_divisor_2 < start:
        last_six_divisor_2 += 6
    candidates_1 = [i for i in range(last_six_divisor_1, end, 6) if gmpy2.is_prime(i)]
    candidates_2 = [i for i in range(last_six_divisor_2, end, 6) if gmpy2.is_prime(i)]
    candidates = [i for i in [2, 3] if start <= i] + candidates_1 + candidates_2
    return candidates


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = 1
    min_p, max_p = 2 ** 32, 2 ** 32 + 1_000_000
    rep, num = 1, 1
    f_name = 'pyfilename'
    times = timeit.repeat(setup=f"from {f_name} import primes_01; start={min_p}; end={max_p}",
                          stmt="primes_01(start, end)", repeat=rep, number=num)
    print(sum(times)/(rep*num))

    # import time
    # start = time.time()
    # primes = primes_01(min_p, max_p)
    # print(f"Dur: {time.time()-start}\n{sum([len(primes[i]) for i in range(len(primes))])}")

EDIT:
The above code completes for me in 0.148s. Pyprimesieve - using a segmented sieve of Eratosthenes for the same range (2^32, 2^32+1,000,000) - Completes in 21.9s (see below code) and seems to have a worse O().
import timeit
min_p, max_p = 2**32, 2**32 + 1_000_000
rep, num = 1, 1
times = timeit.repeat(setup=f"import pyprimesieve; start={min_p}; end={max_p}",
                      stmt="pyprimesieve.primes(start, end)", repeat=rep, number=num)
print(sum(times)/(rep*num))


A segmented sieve of Eratosthenes shouldn't be too slow for this. It's really just sieving up to 2**32 and using the results to sieve a fairly small range of numbers. Really the only reason it's going to go slow here is that Python has a fairly poor overhead:useful-work ratio relative to a lower level language.

one small optimization I can think of is instead of using list addition which create a brand new list is use the extend method in the first to add the elements you produce in the the second list, like so candidates = [i for i in range(last_six_divisor_1, end, 6) if gmpy2.is_prime(i)] then candidates.extend(i for i in range(last_six_divisor_2, end, 6) if gmpy2.is_prime(i)) and finally candidates.extend(i for i in [2, 3] if start <= i)

Thanks @Copperfield for the suggestion. I implemented and compared to the original over 1000 (100reps 10num) interlaced tests (m2, m1, m2, m1... to reduce method bias) but saw an average performance decrease of 0.0364%.  Switched the interlacing order (m2, m1, m2, m1...) and still saw a 0.002% improvement to 0.238 detriment. I'll run more tests; it gives me a new area to try and improve!

@ShadowRanger I added an edit to the post regarding pyprimesive's segmented Eratosthenes; I don't know if you updated your comment after that.
If so, I may need to re-write in C++ for a serious performance improvement. Thanks for the direction.
